# Handlebars linked CSS not found when generating PDF

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, pdf-generation, puppeteer

So I am trying to generate a PDF using Puppeteer and Handlebars. I am doing it by setting the content of a new page and then using Puppeteer to generate the PDF. However I am struggling to get the CSS to link. I have tried using the following code in a simplified project to get it to work using express:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const handlebars = require("handlebars");
var express = require("express");
var hbs = require("express-handlebars");

var app = express();

app.engine('hbs', hbs({ extname: 'hbs' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

(async () => {
    let browser = null;

    const file = fs.readFileSync('./templates/template.hbs', 'utf8');
    const template = handlebars.compile(file);
    const html = template({});

    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setContent(html);
})();
```

This is how my project structure looks:

[image: Folder Structure]

However I can not seem to get my CSS to appear when setting the page content. I have followed a lot of tutorials but I am also not sure if they are applicable to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

What ended up working for me was using `Puppeteers` built in function to set styles for the page:

```js
await page.addStyleTag({ path: './public/css/style.css'});
```

This means I could get rid of all the express code as well. So my final working code looked like so:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require("fs");
const handlebars = require("handlebars");

(async () => {
    let browser = null;

    const file = fs.readFileSync('./templates/template.hbs', 'utf8');
    const template = handlebars.compile(file);
    const html = template({});

    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setContent(html);
    await page.addStyleTag({ path: './public/css/style.css'});
})();
```

You may need to make use of `path` however like I needed to in my main project to get the correct path to the CSS. Like so:

```js
await page.addStyleTag({ path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/css/style.css') });
```

Comment: this worked great. How about load images too?

Comment: @IvanLopes Images I used this piece of code to get the file `fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('${__dirname}/assets, ''));` and then used `Buffer.from('').toString('base64')` to create a base64 string.

Comment: Thanks this is a very interesting solution too. But i manage by passing the full url of the image like: "https://mysite/img/myimage.jpg" in the template. thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while using Puppeteer in a Google Cloud Function. I solved the problem by saving the compiled HTML file to a temporary file in the file system and use `page.goto()` to open the file. This allowed the external images and stylesheet to be loaded. This way, your HTML template not so tightly coupled to your puppeteer script.

```
  const htmlFile = bucket.file('invoices/template/invoice_template.html');
  const html = (await htmlFile.download()).toString();

  // replace template tags with invoice data
  var template = handlebars.compile(html);

  const htmlWithData = template({});

  // save the html to the temp folder
  const tempFilePath = '/tmp/invoice.html';
  fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, htmlWithData);

  // set the html of the page to the invoice template
  await page.goto('file://' + tempFilePath, { waitUntil: 'load' });
  
  // to use page breakpoints
  await page.emulateMediaType('print');

  // generate the pdf
  const pdf = await page.pdf({ 
    format: "letter",
    margin: {
      top: '50px',
      right: '50px',
      bottom: '50px',
      left: '50px',
    }
  });
```